# Mutable Global Variable in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, global, var, mutable

I would like to know if there is a way to create a mutable global variable in Swift? I know that I can declare constants, but I want to change the value.

Thanks

Comment: Just use `var` instead of `let`.

Comment: @Kirsteins couldn't that approach lead to weird behaviours when you try to set the variable from multiple sources at the same time?

Comment: @DánielNagy, only if you are writing multi-threaded code. In that case you better know what you are doing, and add synchronization code.

Comment: @DánielNagy Thread safety is not exclusive to this question. It should be taken into account when dealing with any variable resources.

Answer (score 1):

In swift, you declare variables with var and constants with let.

If you want a global variable, create it a the top of a file, outside of the definition of any enclosing class/struct/enum/etc.

If you will access that variable from multi-threaded code as @DánielNagy mentions in his comment, it's more complex. However accessing global variables from concurrent code is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
class myViewController : UIViewController{
struct GlobalVar{
static var myName : String?
}
override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

in any view controller and access it anywhere by:

```
//Another VC viewDidload
GlobalVar.myName = "Hello"
print(GlobalVar.myName)
```